# fsck will update inode or not in read only filesystem

Tags: fsck

I have custom am335x board with read only file system. I want to use fsck with auto repair broken packages and inode in read only file system.

Will fsck auto update inode and broken packages in read only file system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , The fsck command works directly on data structures stored on disk, which are internal and intrinsically specific to a file system implementation.